# Lotus Notes search displays all emails

Tags: search, lotus-notes

When I do any kind of search in any view of Lotus Notes 9.0.1 it displays the number of search results but doesn't filter them. ALL of my emails are still displayed in my view and I can't see the actual results. Is there a setting that I'm missing? I have "search this view" selected but I still see all of my emails.

Answer (score 1):

When searching the view there are various options. One of them controlls how to display the results. It is called `Show results`. I guess in your case it is set to `Within all documents`. In that case the results are selected in the view, but all documents are still shown. Change it to `By relevance` or any other matching option to get the desired results.

All of these options are only available if a fulltext index exists for your database.